# Compare two columns from two tables and display a result

Tags: php, html, mysql, compare

I'm working on a code by which I have two tables (table 1 named as approved_requests and table 2 named as canceled_requests). What I was trying to do is to compare values in column (event_title) from table 1 with values in column (also named as event_title) from table 2. And if they match I want to display a text , while if they don't match I want to display a button. What is the best way to do it?

Here what I have so far:

```
$name=$_SESSION['name']; //name of the user currently in session
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM approved_requests WHERE user_name ='$name' " ;
            $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die(mysql_error());
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);         
           $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM canceled_requests WHERE user_name ='$name'";
            $result2 = mysql_query("$sql2") or die(mysql_error());          
           $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

if($row['event_title']==row2['event_title']{ ?>

<form action="" method="post">

                    <input type="submit" name="cancel_event" value="Cancel"> 

                </form>
<?php
                }
else {
?>
<b>canceled</b>
}
```

Comment: why don't you just handle with a join in sql?

Comment: @nomistic I found a simple solution that does the job  : 

 $sql  = "select event_title from approved_requests WHERE user_name ='$name' and event_title not in (select event_title from canceled_requests)" ;
            $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die(mysql_error());
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to my questions

```
$sql  = "select event_title from approved_requests WHERE user_name ='$name' and event_title not in (select event_title from canceled_requests)" ;
                $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die(mysql_error());
                $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```